# creating a list of values from entry widget tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a table in **Python GUI**, using entry widgets and obtain the values entered by the user for further calculation in a list.found the snippet below:

[image]

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Please type your code. Do not insert screenshots.

Comment: it is almost correct way. Now find some tutorial. It is only documentation http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
entries = []
varEntry = StringVar()
entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=varEntry)
entry.pack()
entry.bind('Return',addToList)

def addToList():
    entries.append(varEntry)
```